# Validation on integer

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use a validation on Integer input i download and set "DataAnnotationsExtensions"
on my project with this part of code:

```
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;
```

and I use this code in my model :

```
[Integer(ErrorMessage="Please Enter a Number")]
public int PersonID { get; set; }
```

but it didnt work and when app starts the HTML source code is something like this:

> data-val-number="The field PersonID must be a number"

but it has to be something like this:

> data-val-number="Please Enter a Number"

anyone knows anything about this ?

Comment: like @m1kael said, this message appears because of the property's type (built into the MVC framework).  I've read that this can be changed, but not very easily.  It's recommended (for ease) to use a regex attribute.  `[RegularExpression("^\d*$")]`.  That will accept blank or any positive integer.  Change the `*` to a `+` if one or more numbers can be entered.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It's a good Idea but I dont want to use Regex.
if u have any Idea please tell me 
but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `data-val-number` attribute is there because the `PersonID` property is of type `int`. It is not a DataAnnotationsExtensions' attribute.

In your case, DataAnnotationsExtensions add another attribute, `data-val-regex`, which will contain your message, which is displayed in case of an error.

Comment: It's all PersonID input properties but it has no data-val-regex
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PersonID must be a number." data-val-required="this field is requierd" id="PersonID" name="PersonID" type="number" value="" />

Comment: Looks like your DataAnnotationsExtensions do not kick in. Check whether DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProviderExtensions.RegisterValidationExtensions(); is called. Seems like it is not. This line should be in the app start routine. Or to have it done for you, add DataAnnotationsExtensions to your project via NuGet: TOOLS -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console -> PM> Install-Package DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3